# Jenkins Parameterized with batch commands or powershell script

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I want to add to a pipeline parameters of folders and files in a directory on an agent.
e.g when I click on Build with Parameters it will show my checkbox of all the folders&files at c:\project and then I can choose which files I want for the job.
I try using plugin Active Choices Parameter, and to run a groovy script

```
node (node1){
   stage('folders'){
       bat "dir /b /s c:\\project"
   }
}
```

I've tried also with powershell script
`Get-ChildItem -path c:/project1 -Recurse -Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below. I don't have WIndows to test. But this should work on Windows as well. Just provide the correct Path.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { choice(name: 'CHOICES', choices: listFiles("/var/jenkins_home/test"), description: '') }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "Run!!!"
                }
            }
    }
}

@NonCPS
def listFiles(def path) {
     def files= []
     new File(path).traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { file ->
                        files.add(file)
                    }
    return files
}
```